# .ps figure is apparently ok but when compiled inside an includegraphic command it is upside down and very small

Tags: graphics, dvips

I have a template code for pstrick figures that I use because I often have to make figures with the same characteristics. So, this way, I can just fill in the bits of code I need, like plots or drawings or whatever. When I compile this code it gives me a `.ps` figure that looks just fine. However, when I use, in another `.tex` file, this `.ps` figure I obtain a `.pdf` where this image is upside down and very small, not possessing at all the dimensions it should.

The `.tex` file I use to call the `.ps` figure is simply:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[]{testFig.ps}
        \caption{test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get when I compile it:

[image]

And this is how it should look:

[image]

Have any of you ever encountered a problem like this? I have absolutely no idea what is going on.

I left the code of the figure here at the end because it is a bit large. If you have a hint at what may be causing this I'll be glad to hear you.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-plot}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,latexsym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pst-intersect,rotating}
\usepackage{xstring}


\pagestyle{empty}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{borda}{rgb}{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}    % frame and axes
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.91, 0.84, 0.42}    % background


% Frame box
\newcommand{\myframebox}[1]  {\psframebox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=bg,linestyle=none]{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\def\intx{0.4} % data range in the x-axis
\def\inty{100} % data range in the y-axis
%
\def\dvx{25} % 10/intx the ratio between the psfigure x-axis range (10) and     the x-axis data range
\def\dvyT{1} % 10/intx the ratio between the psfigure y-axis range (10) and     the y-axis data range
\def\dvyM{0.5}
\def\dvyB{0.25}
%
\def\cenx{-5.8} % the starting point of the x-axis' labels
\def\cenyT{0} % the starting point of the y-axis' labels
\def\cenyM{0}
\def\cenyB{-8}
%
\def\sx{5.8 add} % shift of the data initial point in the x-axis
\def\syT{0 add} % shift of the data initial point in the y-axis
\def\syM{0 add}
\def\syB{8 add}
%
\def\lax{0.1} % step of the labels in the x-axis
\def\layT{1} % step of the labels in the y-axis
\def\layM{2}
\def\layB{4}
%
\def\mulx{2.5} % lax * divx: plot's range in the x-axis
\def\mulyT{1} % lay * divy: plot's range in the y-axis 
\def\mulyM{1}
\def\mulyB{1}
%
\def\slax{5} % number of subdivisions between labels in the x-axis
\def\slayT{2} % number of subdivisions between labels in the y-axis
\def\slayM{2}
\def\slayB{2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\myscaleT{
\psset{algebraic,xunit=1.9cm,yunit=0.9cm}
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=bg,linestyle=none](0,0)(10,10)
\pstScalePoints(\dvx, \dvyT)\sx\syT
}

\def\myscaleM{
\psset{algebraic,xunit=1.9cm,yunit=0.9cm}
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=bg,linestyle=none](0,0)(10,10)
\pstScalePoints(\dvx, \dvyM)\sx\syM
}

\def\myscaleB{
\psset{algebraic,xunit=1.9cm,yunit=0.9cm}
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=bg,linestyle=none](0,0)(10,10)
\pstScalePoints(\dvx, \dvyB)\sx\syB
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\myaxlabT}[1]{
\psaxes[labels=#1,Ox=\cenx,Dx=\lax,dx=\mulx,Oy=\cenyT,Dy=\layT,dy=\mulyT,xsubticks=\slax,ysubticks=\slayT,
linewidth=1.5pt,tickwidth=0.1pt,linecolor=borda,tickstyle=inner,
ticksize=-4pt     4pt,axesstyle=frame,ylabelsep=2pt,ylabelOffset=0pt,xlabelsep=2pt,tickcolor=borda    ,
subtickcolor=borda,labelFontSize=\bf \Large\color{borda},
%  xlabelFactor={^\circ},
](0,0)(10,10)
}

\newcommand{\myaxlabM}[1]{
\psaxes[labels=#1,Ox=\cenx,Dx=\lax,dx=\mulx,Oy=\cenyM,Dy=\layM,dy=\mulyM,xsubtic    ks=\slax,ysubticks=\slayM,
linewidth=1.5pt,tickwidth=0.1pt,linecolor=borda,tickstyle=inner,
ticksize=-4pt     4pt,axesstyle=frame,ylabelsep=2pt,ylabelOffset=0pt,xlabelsep=2pt,tickcolor=borda    ,
subtickcolor=borda,labelFontSize=\bf \Large\color{borda},
%  xlabelFactor={^\circ},
](0,0)(10,10)
}

\newcommand{\myaxlabB}[1]{
\psaxes[labels=#1,Ox=\cenx,Dx=\lax,dx=\mulx,Oy=\cenyB,Dy=\layB,dy=\mulyB,xsubtic    ks=\slax,ysubticks=\slayB,
linewidth=1.5pt,tickwidth=0.1pt,linecolor=borda,tickstyle=inner,
ticksize=-4pt     4pt,axesstyle=frame,ylabelsep=2pt,ylabelOffset=0pt,xlabelsep=2pt,tickcolor=borda    ,
subtickcolor=borda,labelFontSize=\bf \Large\color{borda},
%  xlabelFactor={^\circ},
](0,0)(10,10)
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}



% Do not let spaces between lines or else the MULTIDO may not work
\psset{algebraic,xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm}
\begin{pspicture}(0,-1.75)(21,27.95)
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=borda!20,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=borda,line    style=solid](0,0)(21,29.7)
%
%
% TOP FIGURE
\uput[r](0.8,20.0){
\myscaleT
%
\myaxlabT{y}
%
}
%
%
% MID FIGURE
\uput[r](0.8,10.6){
\myscaleM
%
%
\myaxlabM{y}
%
}
%
%
%BOTTOM FIGURE
\uput[r](0.8,1.2){
\myscaleB
%
%
\myaxlabB{all}
%
}

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: with `latex`, `dvips`, `ps2pdf` I get a full-page figure with descending numbers (although slightly vertically misaligned). The `.ps` is as you describe (very small and upside down). Note: your MWE is broken (some extra spaces, e.g., `xsubtic    ks`. Also: it's not minimal, you could have drawn, e.g., just a single axis to illustrate the problem.